# MySQL : STR_TO_DATE function giving null on correct output with format

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to convert string to date in `mysql`. Inspite of giving correct string and format specifier, `mysql` is giving `NULL` output with warning message as `Incorrect datetime value: 'XXXXX' for function str_to_date` although it is working for full date string.

**mysql logs**

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2018/06', '%Y/%m');
+---------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2018/06', '%Y/%m') |
+---------------------------------+
| NULL                            |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2018/06/01', '%Y/%m/%d');                                                                                                                                                            +---------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2018/06/01', '%Y/%m/%d') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2018-06-01                            |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**debug info**

MySQL version - `5.7.21 MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                      |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2018/06' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Requirement*

I want to parse month and year from above date string.

Comment: it's in the manual... "This is the inverse of the DATE_FORMAT() function. It takes a string str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts. If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning. " "2018/06" is not a valid DATE..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Above statement is conflicting with this statement from manual - Unspecified date or time parts have a value of 0, so incompletely specified values in `str` produce a result with some or all parts set to 0. Check out manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: "Above statement is conflicting with this statement from manual" No the docs are conflicting with MySQL's execution.. @Vivek check this the statement is copied directly from the manual https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jPKVi2wpFyKFfQH4XLzemR/1  might because off sql_mode NO_ZERO_IN_DATE .. yes this confirms it https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jPKVi2wpFyKFfQH4XLzemR/1

Comment: Mine last comment also answers this question why `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2018/06', '%Y/%m')` does not work it's because off the NO_ZERO_IN_DATE sql_mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fulfilling my requirement, I'm using following workaround -

```
mysql> SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2018/06', '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d'));
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2018/06', '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d')) |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    2018 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2018/06', '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d'));
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2018/06', '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d')) |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                        6 |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE_FORMAT function in mysql

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2018/06/01', '%Y-%m')
```

NB: The date string should be in any valid MYSQL DATE FORMAT(Year month day)

Comment: I want to extract year and month from date string, how your solution will help me get that, please explain.

Comment: If your date string is always in 'yyyy/mm' format, instead of using date function why cant you use substring function in mysql.

Comment: If I'm using date function then, I can use any date formatter function like `MONTHNAME` to get the name of month and from substring, it won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your date string is always in 'yyyy/mm' format

instead of using date function you can use substring OR substring_index function in MYSQL.

```
 select substring("2018/06",1,4) AS year, substring("2018/06",6,2) as month
```

OR

```
select substring_index("2018/06","/",1) AS year, substring_index("2018/06","/",-1) as month
```